# How add a specific variable in custom AuthStorage in Zend Framework 2

Tags: session, authentication, interface, zend-framework2, storage

I'm working on ZF2 and I have developped my own storage for authentication but I wonder how to add a new persistent variable (session-like).

Look My Auth Storage :

```
  <?php

namespace Application\Model;

use Zend\Authentication\Storage;
use Zend\Authentication\Storage\StorageInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManagerAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
use Application\Model\User;

class MyAuthStorage implements Storage\StorageInterface, ServiceManagerAwareInterface
{

    protected $storage;
    protected $userTable;
    protected $resolvedIdentity;
    protected $serviceManager;


    public function isEmpty() {
        [...]
    }

    public function read() {
        [...]
    }

    public function write($contents) {
        [...]
    }

    public function clear() {
        [...]
    }

    public function getStorage() {
        [...]
    }

    public function setStorage(Storage\StorageInterface $storage) {
        [...]
    }

    public function getUserTable() {
        [...]
    }

    public function getServiceManager() {
        [...]
    }

    public function setServiceManager(ServiceManager $serviceManager) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

I would like to add a variable called **foo** in my storage (my session ?)

I try this, but it doesn't work :

```
protected $foo;
        public function setFoo($value) {
            $this->foo= $value;
        }

        public function getFoo() {
            return $this->foo;
        }
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found something and it works for me :

I've added these things in my auth storage class

```
use Zend\Session\Container;
```

Then,

```
    protected $container;

    public function setContainer(Container $container) {
        $this->container = $container;
        return $this->container;
    }

    public function getContainer() {
        if (!isset($this->container)) {
            $this->setContainer(new Container('myauthstorage'));
        }
        return $this->container;
    }
```

And now I can do in my controller stuff like that :

```
$container = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('AuthService')->getStorage()->getContainer();  

$container->foo = true;

if ($container->foo) {
// Congrats !
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good example how to write last login time.

```
namespace Application\Model;

use Zend\Authentication\Storage;

class AuthStorage extends Storage\Session
{

    public function setRememberMe($rememberMe = 0, $time = 1209600)
    {
        if ($rememberMe == 1) {
            $this->session->getManager()->rememberMe($time);
        }
    }

    public function forgetMe()
    {
        $this->session->getManager()->forgetMe();
    }

    public function lastLogin()
    {
        $this->session->{$this->getMember()}->last_login = time();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial :

http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/zend-framework-2-create-login-authentication-using-authenticationservice-with-rememberme/

Sounds like your personnal AuthStorage should extends `Storage\Session` like this :

```
namespace SanAuth\Model;

use Zend\Authentication\Storage;

class MyAuthStorage extends Storage\Session
{
    public function setRememberMe($rememberMe = 0, $time = 1209600)
    {
         if ($rememberMe == 1) {
             $this->session->getManager()->rememberMe($time);
         }
     }

    public function forgetMe()
    {
        $this->session->getManager()->forgetMe();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, my Storage is the same of https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/src/ZfcUser/Authentication/Storage/Db.php.
So it doesn't extend from `Storage\Session`

Comment: Hmmm. Try this : for the setter, instead of `$this->foo = value` try `$this->getStorage()->foo(value)`. I think you can't just access it with $this->foo, you have to use the storage object.

Comment: It doesn't work. It's not a persistent var.
PS: Look up, I found the solution